# How can i show the jpanel?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I make a movie theater system. And i keep the movies and movie theaters in a jTable. Also I'm trying to show the movie theater. Movie theater seats made from JButton and I keep these seats in a jpanel.

How can i show the seats when the movie theater selected?

And this is my code.

```
final ArrayList<JPanel> panels = new ArrayList<>();


    for(int k=0;k<theater.size();k++){
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBounds(500, 0, 500, 500);
        contentPane.add(panel);

        int y = theater.get(k).getCapacity();
        int x = 500/y;          

        for(int i=0;i<y;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<y;j++){
                JButton button = new JButton(letters[i]+numbers[j]);
                button.setBounds(500 + x*j, 0 + x*i, x-5, x-5);
                panel.add(button);
            }
        }
        repaint();
        panels.add(panel);      
    }
```

Comment: what is `contentPane` here?

Comment: It is in jframe. It isn't important.

Comment: You cannot know what is important before posting an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: Most probably you are using `null` layout?

Comment: Yes you are right.@Braj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't** use `setBounds()` method instead leave it for Layout Manger to set the size and position of the components that why it's made for.

Use proper layout for this design such as [GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html), [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html) etc.

Read more about layout [How to Use Various Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/layoutlist.html)

---

Don't directly add the components in the `JFrame`'s content pane instead first add the components in another container such as `JPanel` then finally add it in the `JFrame`'s content pane.

Comment: Can i use the grid layout just for the jpanel?

Comment: Sure why not. Read more about it then if it's as per your design then use it and remove all `setBounds` methods.

Comment: But i want to do this in right side of the jFrame. How can i will do that without setBounds()?

Comment: you can use multiple container such as `JPanel` add the components in it with proper layout. I can't help you until and unless I have full testable code.